# How to pass concrete class as a parameter to a method expecting an interface it implements

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a couple of interfaces like this:

```
public interface IAppointment<TUser> where TUser : IUser
{
    string TeamName { get; set; }
    TUser Host { get; set; }
    string HostNameForGuest { get; }
    bool HostNameVisible { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public interface IUser
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The use of a generic for the `IAppointment` interface is because one of the classes where I'm implementing it is auto-generated by Entity Framework and I can't change the return type of the `Host` property from `User` (the name of the database entity it describes) to `IUser`. This implementation is shown below. The other properties specified in the interface are already present in the EF-generated partial class of the same name.

```
public partial class Appointment : IAppointment<User>
{   
    public string HostNameForGuest
    {
        get
        {
            return AppointmentHelper.HostNameForGuest(this);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the value for the `HostNameForGuest` property from a function, the reason being that I want to reuse the logic for deriving the value in multiple other classes which implement the same interface. The function looks like this:

```
public static string HostNameForGuest(IAppointment<IUser> appointment)
{
    return appointment.HostNameVisible ? $"{appointment.Host.FirstName} appointment.Host.LastName}" : appointment.TeamName;
}
```

The problem I have is that the above code throws an IntelliSense error for the line

```
return AppointmentHelper.HostNameForGuest(this);
```

Underlining `this` and saying:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AppointmentBooking.DAL.Appointment' to 'AppointmentBooking.Global.Interfaces.IAppointment<AppointmentBooking.Global.Interfaces.IUser>'

I understand the error but I don't know how to fix it. I realise this is just exposing a shortcoming in my knowledge of generics, which are not something I've used often, and it's probably just a case of expressing the parameters correctly, but no combination I've tried has worked so far. I've tried modifying the line to:

```
return AppointmentHelper.HostName(this<User>);
```

and

```
return AppointmentHelper.HostName(this<IUser>);
```

both of which yield the error

> 'User' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

(`'User'` is `'IUser'` in the error message for the second example, obviously).

So what's the correct way to pass the class that implements `IAppointment<IUser>` as a parameter to the function which accepts the interface type as a parameter?

## EDIT

The questions which have been suggested as duplicates for this all seem to boil down to people trying to convert a derived class to its base class. I don't *think* that's what I'm doing, though I'm quite prepared to be told I'm wrong.

For a start, I'm not inheriting a class, I'm implementing an interface.

Secondly, I don't have any complaints from the compiler when I take out the `IUser` interface. This doesn't throw the error:

```
public interface IAppointment
{
    string TeamName { get; set; }
    string HostNameForGuest { get; }
    bool HostNameVisible { get; set; }
}
```

```
public partial class Appointment : IAppointment
{   
    public string HostNameForGuest
    {
        get
        {
            return AppointmentHelper.HostNameForGuest(this);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static string HostNameForGuest(IAppointment appointment)
{
    return appointment.HostNameVisible ? $"{appointment.Host.FirstName} appointment.Host.LastName}" : appointment.TeamName;
}
```

If the problem was me trying to convert the "derived" `Appointment` class (I don't know if "derived" is the right term for a class that implements an interface or if it refers specifically to a class that inherits another class) to the "base" class `IAppointment` (again, it's an interface, not a base class) then I'd still expect to get the same error. Wouldn't I..?

Comment: IMO I don't think generics are offering you any benefits here, only needless complicating things (unless it's doing some other heavy lifting not shown in your post). Why not make `IAppointment` non-generic and let the `Host` property be of type `IUser`?

Comment: Looks like you should be able in this case to declare `interface IAppointment<out TUser> where ...`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever unfortunately the compiler will complain about `TUser Host` being in an invariant position.

Comment: @Luke The generic was necessary because, without it, the compiler complained that the property `Host` in my EF-generated class did not have a return type of `IUser`. Which it doesn't - its return type is `User` - but I can't change the EF-generated class. Adding the generic in this way got around that.